# Animation Nodes: Create Polygon Indices List

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to create a Mesh from scratch, using Animation Nodes (V2.1.4 in Blender 2.8).

In the first step, I want to create a triangle fan with n individual triangles.

So I have a loop, that creates the vertices - no problem here:

[image]

But it seems like I sill don't understand polygon indices.

The way i thought it functions is:
I have my polygon p1 with three vertices v1, v2, v3 and poligon indices: p1: 0,1,2

My lists produce exactly that - but that doesnt work.

[image]

The full loop:

[image]

and the error I'm getting:

[image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mesh that have polygons **has** to have edges that align with those polygons. In this case, you haven't provided edge indices to the node, so a mesh can't be created. The easiest way to create edge indices is to use the *Edges From Polygons* node.

Comment: Great, that was it. Can you give me more information on when to use edges? The AN-Docs for the "create polygon indices"-node have almost the exact thing going on, but only use the vertex- and polygon-index-input.
https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/mesh/operators/create_polygon_indices.html

Comment: @bstnhnsl This documentation is for Animation Nodes 2.0. The behavior changed since then. In the beta version you are using, you have to provide edges explicitly.